# How to optimize N filterbank vectors?

Tags: c++, matrix, signal-processing, mfcc

I have 40 triangular Mel-spaced filterbank vectors with 257 element each.

I want to multiply them with my power spectrum (generated using FFT of 20ms audio frame) result and then sum the results so I can get mel-spaced power spectrum.

The problem though is having 257 value where most of the values are zero is kind of overkill. Simply, I can only store non-zero elements instead of the whole 257 value, but I think there is a smarter way to apply multiple filterbanks, probably using matrix multiplication. Is my reasoning correct? If yes how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FFT's are also 257 points so it's a straightforward elementwise multiplication? Your filterbanks probably will have most of their zeroes at the edges. If you store per filterbank the index of the first and last non-zero element, you can probably eliminate a lot of those zeroes and just store the slice between min and max.

So, to multiply an FFT with that filterbank, you set all FFT coeffecients below min and above max to zero, and you only multiply the slices between min and max.

Comment: That what I was thinking, just thought there be a (smarter?) way using matrix multiplication. maybe? (store the frames in a matrix and multiply with the filterbank vector? but intuitively the first method will be faster than matrix multiplication.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is quite unlikely to beat not multiplying at all ;)